# How to exclude files from compilation when using msvc (cl.exe)

Tags: batch-file, visual-c++, cmd, cl

I'm wondering how I would exclude a file from being built within my batch file. Currently, my cl.exe compiliation line within the batch file looks like this:

```
cl /c ..\source\*.c
```

so how would I say I would like to build all files EXCEPT "file_not_needed.c" from the build?

Comment: Can you not list them dynamically to a file, e.g `file.ext`, excluding that file using perhaps `find.exe` or `findstr.exe`, then use `@file.ext` in your command line instead of a file mask/glob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file(s) with the file extension `c` to exclude can be temporarily renamed with changing the file extension to exclude them.

A single command line for a single **C** source code file for usage in a command prompt window or a batch file:

```
ren ..\source\file_not_needed.c file_not_needed.c.tmp & cl.exe /c ..\source\*.c & ren ..\source\file_not_needed.c.tmp file_not_needed.c
```

A multi-line solution for multiple **C** source code files for usage in a batch file:

```
for %%I in (file_not_needed "one more file not needed") do ren "..\source\%%~I.c" "%%~I.c.tmp"
cl.exe /c ..\source\*.c
for %%I in ("..\source\*.c.tmp") do ren "%%I" "%%~nI"
```

All the files to exclude must be specified inside the round brackets of first **FOR** loop using a space, comma or semicolon as separator between the file names without file extension.